# enabling a button after checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a submit button in my code, and its disabled.. I need it to be enable when the user clicks on the " I agree" check box.. I need it to be in jQuery.. can anyone help me with it? I'm writing my code in html, javascript and jquery..

```
 <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="agree" >I agree to the terms of      service...<br> <br />
     <div align="center">
     <button  style=" color: white; background-color: gray; width: 100px; height: 30px" type="submit" disabled ><b><font color="black">Register</font></b></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you at least tried a google search before posing this question…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the state of the checkbox changes, set the `disabled` property of the button based on the checkboxes' current state:

```
$('#agree').on('change', function() {
  $('button').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

If you have multiple buttons on the page, the above will set the `disabled` property on all of them. If you need to get the next button relative to `#agree`, you'd have to traverse a little bit:

```
$('~ div:first', this).find('button').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
```

`$('~ div:first', this)` will get the first occurrence of a `div` which comes after `this` (`#agree`)

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD2XP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#agree').click(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

or:

```
$('#agree').click(function() {
    $(this).next().find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Property of button changes when Checkbox state is changed...

```
$('#agree').click(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD2XP/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkBoxID").click(function() {
  $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

so in your case

```
$("#agree").click(function() {
  $("button").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZu2W/)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$('#agree').change(function() {

       $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a JS solution, but just to show a different approach, you can actually accomplish something similar in pure CSS.

Note you should also avoid using the `font` tag, and move your CSS from inline to a stylesheet.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Ynf7J/)

HTML

```
<input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="agree">I agree to the terms of service...
<div>
    <button>Register</button>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
div div {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
button {
    background:grey;
    color:#c0c0c0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div div {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div button {
    background:#c0c0c0;
    color:black;
}
```